# How to search and sort in J2me (ascending or descending)

Tags: java-me, midp, rms

I am wondering about how to search in J2ME. I have been searching in the internet, so many result show to me, and I see in *Java2s.com* I got a result use `RecordFilter` and matches method for search in record store.

But my problem is, when I need to pass 2 or more parameters into it. How can result matches with these parameter?

And how to sort descending or ascending like bubble sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenate your searches into a single String variable. Separate each of them with `;` for example. In the code of the `matches` method explode the String to get each search criteria.
To make the filter in effect create an instance of SearchFilter and call the `matches` method with the concantenated String as its param.
For the `sort` implement the `RecordComparator` interface ; implement the `compare` method to build your sort criteria. Make a google search about j2me+recordcomparator to see examples about how to make sorts.

---

**EDIT :**

In the code of the `matches` method explode the String param obtained from the byte[] param. Treat each String exploded to make the criteria.
As I understand you want to pass two string as a search criteria when you wrote :

```
SearchFilter search = new SearchFilter(txtSearch.getString(), strType);
```

So in the constructor there should be two params !!!

When you want to make the matching then call

`if searchFilter.matches((search1+";"+sType).getBytes())`

Then explode the `candidate` param into two String when you code the `matches` method.

Comment: thank you pheromix, but i confuse about matches, i dont understand what you mean in matches method, could you give me code sample?

Comment: but stringsearch still concetenate with ";"?

Comment: i have posted all my functino search in search file into question, what should i do with `if(search.matches(string.getBytes());`

Comment: can u explain for me about how did matches in SearchFilter Class work? because as you mention above, 2 string must be combined in one string and it has been separate by ";" <== i confuse about this because how can i check paramater what i pass in into it? example Str = str1 + ";" + str2. and what should matches method do inside it? Thank You very much!

Comment: First of all thank you again !! but i think my matches code not true, you can see my edit code in question. because i do follow your answer i just got only first result in result set. and it not matche with my criteria, my criteria is when user enter value into textbox in show all result in resultset and when use search with textbox and choicegroup it must filter resultset follow value of choicegroup!!


Thank you Very much

Comment: Hello Pheromix, i can do it, but i got new problem, my record data store like this structure: `1; abc;def;hkt;` when i enter bc and def i could get a result but when i enter ab and def or hkt and def i couldn't get any result from recordstore. I know when end of string or full of string before; and after ";" were entered, it would be got from record, but how can it filter relative. It mean when i enter ab and def, it will appear exactly what i need???? Thank You

Comment: I guess that you made a mistake when exploding the strings , make a System.out.println to show all of them. Be careful when exctracting the strings ( using `substr` and the `indexOf(";")` or `indexOf(";")+1` )

Comment: hey pheromix in filter search class i list all record in recordstore and then use int     `iID = record.indexOf(";");
                      sID = record.substring(0,iID);` and `int iName = record.indexOf(";", iID+1);
                      sName= record.substring(iID + 1,iName);`  to explore 2 parameter and what should i do in this if statement ? `if(what condition for if?){
                     //what should i do inside if?
                     }`  Thank You

Comment: it's up to you ! you implement your search criteria there !

Answer (score 0):

When I save my Data in RMS I save it as a String[] like I want to save Name, Age,Salary,EmpID for each employee I save it create an array and convert it to bytes and save it in RMS. When i retrieve it i do the reverse process. Now if i want to get employee with names starting with A and with salary 10000 i use the following filter

```
class UtilFilter implements RecordFilter{    
    public UtilFilter(String str_searchText,String str_searchText1)
    {
            this.str_searchText = str_searchText.toLowerCase();
            this.str_searchText1 = str_searchText1.toLowerCase();
    }
    public boolean matches(byte[] bt_byteData)
    {
      String str_str = "";
      String str_str1 = "";
      //here goes code how u get back ur String[] from RMS say u get it in Data
      str_str = Data[0].trim();
      str_str1 = gd_cd.Data[2].trim();

      if(str_searchText != null && str_searchText1 != null && str_str.equals(str_searchText) && str_str1.equals(str_searchText1 ))
        {
              return true;
        }
        else
        {
              return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This way i can filter any no of parameters.Hope tht helps! :)